# Why I can't iterate on the object of this array in a nested iteration?

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, arraylist, collections

I have the following problem iterating on a collection into a JSP page.

This is the code of my JSP:

```
<%@ page import="com.myproject.xmlns.EDILM.SalReport.SalDettaglio" %>
<%@ page import="com.myproject.xmlns.EDILM.SalReport.RM" %>
<!-- showSalwf.jsp -->
<html>
<head>
    <title>Libretti</title>

    <link href="css/business_thema.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/dataTables/datatable.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #TabellaSalwf2 {
            background-color: #99FFFF;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<%
    out.println("TEST SALWF");

%>

    <table id="TabellaSalwf">
        <tr><td>-</td></tr>
        <%
        for (SalDettaglio salDettaglio : (SalDettaglio[]) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("salDettaglio")) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=salDettaglio.getCodice()%></td>
            <td><%=salDettaglio.getStato()%></td>
            <td><%=salDettaglio.getDataCreazione()%></td>
            <td><%=salDettaglio.getDataRegistrazione()%></td>
            <td><%=salDettaglio.getAutoreConvalida()%></td>
            <td><%=salDettaglio.getAutoreConvalida()%></td>
            <td><%=salDettaglio.getAutoreAcquisizione()%></td>
        </tr>
       <%}%>
    </table>

    <br />


    <table id="TabellaSalwf2" border="1">
        <%
        for (SalDettaglio salDettaglio : (SalDettaglio[]) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("salDettaglio")) {
        %>
            <tr id="salDettaglioRow">
                <td><%=salDettaglio.getCodice()%></td>
                <td><%=salDettaglio.getStato()%></td>
                <td><%=salDettaglio.getDataCreazione()%></td>
                <td><%=salDettaglio.getDataRegistrazione()%></td>
                <td><%=salDettaglio.getAutoreCreazione()%></td>
                <td><%=salDettaglio.getAutoreConvalida()%></td>
                <td><%=salDettaglio.getAutoreAcquisizione()%></td>
                <td><%=salDettaglio.getTotImponibile().toString()%></td>
                <td><%=salDettaglio.getFornitore()%></td>
                <td><%=salDettaglio.getRmConRiserva()%></td>
                <td><%=salDettaglio.getErrore()%></td>
            </tr>

            <%

                for (RM currentRM : salDettaglio.getRM()) {

                }

            %>

        <%}%>

    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see there is a table that contains 2 nested iteration. I have no problem with the first iteration (the most external): this iteration retrieve an **array** of **SalDettaglio** objects from the session and iterate on this object printing all the fields of each **SalDettaglio** object as a row.

Now each **SalDettaglio** object contains itself an array of **RM** objects.

Now I have to iterate also on the object of this array (in the inner iteration).

The problem is that with these lines I can't do it:

```
for (RM currentRM : salDettaglio.getRM()) {
    // DO SOME OPERATIONS ON EACH OBJECT
}
```

Using the debugger I see that **salDettaglio.getRM()** is an array of 2 **RM** objects but in the debugger say **Cannot find local variable for 'currentRM'** (that have to contain the current **RM** object into the retrieved array).

Why it don't work? How can I fix this issue?

Tnx

Comment: Why doesn't it work? What is the error message?

Comment: Please show an example of code that produces error. The code you posted makes no use of `currentRM`

Comment: Don't give me any error but in the deugger the currentRM variable is not initialized and in the deubugger say "Cannot find local variable for 'currentRM'"

Comment: Where do you place your breakpoint? Please put some code into the inner loop and try again.

Comment: Ok...putting some code into the inner loop works fine. I thought that the object was initialized also if there was not declared operations on it. If you want write an official response I will accept it :-)

Comment: Why don't you try to use the other form of the for, just to see what happens, for (int i = 0; i < salDettaglio.getRM().length; i++) in any case, I'd tell you that you should try also declaring variables to work with your iterations, maybe the problem could be there.

Comment: Unrelated, but ew: this is 2014, I'd seriously consider writing apps in a more-modern fashion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner loop has no code in it. Because of that, you can't place your breakpoint in any place where the `currentRM` is certain to be defined. In fact, it's conceivable that the whole loop is optimized out.